# how Customer can download Opencart Voucher after purchasing product instead of receiving it through e-mail

Tags: opencart2.x

I am new to Opencart.Feeling difficult to do a task.I need your help on the below task.Please help me out.

Customers can download the voucher using a chosen voucher template (Happy Birthday or something)
The vouchers are for the service items in the menu page (the items and prices are listed in the menu page).

If they choose 1 service(ex:Nail Treatment) item from the menu  it’s the same  price($25) as per the menu

But,If they choose 2 service items they get a 5% off from the total of the 2 items they choose(then its $25x2 minus 5%)

So the value of the voucher depends on what item they choose from the menu
Then they can download the voucher using a chosen design (Happy Birthday or something)

Please let me know,how to do above task.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Well, do you realize your title asks completely different thing from what is asked in description?

OpenCart does not allow (in default) to give discounts/sales on vouchers nor gift vouchers. If you want to achieve this you have to transform those gift vouchers into real products (with download where an image or PDF of voucher could be downloaded). This will solve both of your problems.

On a gift voucher as a product you can set the discount (if more than one piece is bought) or even sale. If the download is present user is able to *download* it manually from his account.

Comment: I have got basic idea on how to achieve above task,Thanks for brief description.

Comment: Feel free to come back to accept the answer if it helps to achieve your goals.